# Backsplash moulding with an outlet

Tags: trim, backsplash

So I made the mistake of hiring a handyman to put in our beautiful butcher block counter tops the other day, and they left a 3/4 inch gap between the countertop and wall, which used to be covered by a 3/4 inch back splash that we also wanted replaced.

So on the advice of the designer, we bought some nice pine boards and had them tacked up. The idea now is to add some moulding and footing to make it blend a little better with the butcher block. Does anyone have any ideas how to get around the outlets that are going to be near the back splash? we're racking our brains and would rather not pull the pine boards down.
[image: The dreaded wall]
[image: The other dreaded wall]

Comment: I guess moving the outlet up a little isn't an option?  It seems like it's either that or having a gap in your cap molding.

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion, the splash needs to be removed and point up the wall were the old splash used to reside and repaint. Then install a splash using the same specie of wood the countertop is made of, but prefinish it ahead of time before it is installed. No other blending needed.